# onclicklistener not working inside a method

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have to put a list of names queried from database into a list (not listview). I am able to do that by inflating a linearlayout with a custom view. I have a created a new class in which there is a method which inflates the layout with the custom view. 
In that method I have implemented a onclicklistener, but it is not working. 
Code:

```
public static void showPeopleInvitedList(Context context, View view, final LinearLayout layout) {
    dbAdapter = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    String[] ENTRIES = dbAdapter.getItems("user_friend_name");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.people, layout, false);

        view.setId(layout.getChildCount() + 1);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        view.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
        layout.addView(view, 0, params);    


    }

    myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("click", "clicked");
            layout.removeView(v);
        }
    };
}
```

But onclicklistener is not working. I am calling this method in the main activity. This method is inside a class which extends LinearLayout
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not yet instantiated myClickListener, so you are setting the view's `onClickListener` to `null`. Move its initialization to before your `for` loop.

```
public static void showPeopleInvitedList(Context context, View view, final LinearLayout layout) {
    dbAdapter = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    String[] ENTRIES = dbAdapter.getItems("user_friend_name");

    myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("click", "clicked");
            layout.removeView(v);
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.people, layout, false);

        view.setId(layout.getChildCount() + 1);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        view.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
        layout.addView(view, 0, params);    


    }
```

}

Comment: Damn! Thanks a lot. I wasted an hour fixing this. Thank you!